# How to use stack navigation, drawer navigation and tab navigation simultaneously in react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm looking to render the drawer navigation, tab navigation and stack navigation simultaneously in my app.
but I'm getting this error:

[image: react navigation error]

This is my `root.js` file content:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {Like, Home, Search, Media, Profile, Direct, HeaderProfile, CustomDrawer } from './components/index';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
```

This the tab navigation code:

```
const Tab =createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const MyTabs=()=>{

return(

    <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Media" component={Media} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Like" component={Like} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />

  </Tab.Navigator>
)}
```

This the drawer navigation code:

```
onst Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyDrawer=()=> {
  return (

      <Drawer.Navigator>

        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />

      </Drawer.Navigator>

  );}
```

And this stack navigation code: (I've imported two above components into stack navigation)

```
        const Stack= createStackNavigator();

        const MainStack=()=>{

        return(

        <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} options={{headerShown:false}}  />
        <Stack.Screen name="MyDrawer" component={MyDrawer}   />
        <Stack.Screen name="Direct" component={Direct} />


        </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

        )}
```

I should say when i remove drawer navigation, everything works without any problem

This the code i implemented to open drawer in `profile.js` :

```
const HeaderProfile = (props) => {

const {navigation}=props;


    return (


            <View >

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={()=>navigation.openDrawer()}

                />
           </View >
                    )}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this same problem for a whole week. Yes, I am a beginner, but this youtube video helped me. (React Native #21: React Navigation(New Version) Mix Tabs + Drawer + Stack) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7wZSA176kE

Comment: Thanks buddy, I figure it out

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

i cant undrastand where you used `HeaderProfile`
but what you want to achieve is simple, just use the following structure:

`DrawerNavigator
    StackNavigator
        TabNavigator`

then from inside your stack navigator header you can open and
close drawer manually

Comment: I created a custom header  named ```HeaderProfile``` and imported that into profile screen, Regarding to  your solution it wouldn't work because if i import ```StackNavigator``` into ```TabNavigator``` it would created a new tab and i don't want to do this